# bmp file processing

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

can some help write a code in c to get 24 bit bmp pixel values into 2d array for processing of it 
thnx in advance

Comment: What did you try? What problems did you encounter? Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 4):

This article details converting bitmaps into C arrays.

http://www.hackpadsoftware.com/projects/bmp_to_c_array.html

I wonder if you even bothered to google this, there were many different websites that talk about this and provide code.

Comment: I agree that its quicker to google this common question that to actually type the question ^^

Answer (score 4):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) about the BMP file format contains extensive information about the format, including the data structures for C/C++ to read it. That's a good starting point.